# Loading A text along with a picture using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made a photo gallery in my website using the following:

```
    /*Begin Photo Gallery Code*/
    var images = ['g1.jpg', 'g2.jpg', 'g3.jpg', 'g4.jpg'];

    function loadImage(src) {           
        $('#pic').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).html('<img src="' + src + '" />').fadeIn('slow');       

        });
    }

    function goNext() {
        var next = $('#gallery>img.current').next();            
        if(next.length == 0)
            next = $('#gallery>img:first');

        $('#gallery>img').removeClass('current');           
        next.addClass('current');
        loadImage(next.attr('src'));
    }

    $(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            $('#gallery').append('<img src="images/gallery/' + images[i] + '" />');             

        }


        $('#gallery>img').click(function() {
            $('#gallery>img').removeClass('current');

            loadImage($(this).attr('src'));
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });

        loadImage('images/gallery/' + images[0]);
        $('#gallery>img:first').addClass('current');

        setInterval(goNext, 4000);
    });
```

It loads one picture at a time from a set of four pictures. Also I have four html files, each of them being relevant to one of the pictures. I want to use JavaScript/JQuery/AJAX to load the relevant html file's content along with the shown picture. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

Should I put the ajax files (4 html files) into a JavaScript array or something?

```
var ajaxPages=['ajax1.html','ajax2.html','ajax3.html','ajax4.html'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the html?  Where are you trying to add the ajax loaded content at?

Comment: Yes of course: check it out: http://codepad.org/o4Uh7bK1

Comment: I want to inject Ajax content into $('#story#text')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the HTML files supposed to change somehow during their displaying, should either output them via your server-side code in hidden `div`s with the request (would be the correct way of doing it) or use AJAX to save them in a variable or create hidden `div`s.

First you need two arrays like this:

```
var ajaxPages=['ajax1.html','ajax2.html','ajax3.html','ajax4.html'];//File Names
var divPages=['div1','div2','div3','div4'];//Div ids in order
```

For the AJAX part you should use something like:

```
var getHtml = function(filename,divid){
    $.post('html/'+filename, function(data) {
    //The first argument is your file location
    //Second one is the callback, data is the string retrieved                               
        $('#'+divid).html(data);
    });
}

$.each(ajaxPages,function(index,value){
    getHtml(value,divPages[index]);
});
```

That should do it... Do tell me if you require further explanation.

EDIT:

```
var ajaxPages=['ajax1.html','ajax2.html','ajax3.html','ajax4.html'];
var divId="yourdivid";
var textArray=new Array();
var currentImg=0;

var getHtml = function(filename){
    $.post('html/'+filename, function(data) {                             
       textArray.push(data);//Save data inside the array textArray
    });
}

$.each(ajaxPages,function(index,value){
    getHtml(value,divPages[index]);
});
```

Then your goNext() method:

```
function goNext() {
    var next = $('#gallery>img.current').next();            
    if(next.length == 0){
        next = $('#gallery>img:first');
        currentImg=0;
    }else{
        currentImg++;
    }

    $('#gallery>img').removeClass('current');           
    next.addClass('current');
    loadImage(next.attr('src'));

     $('#'+divId).html(textArray[currentImg]);//Adds text to div based on current picture
}
```

That should be working fine!

Comment: Thanks. I already have a 'div' with the id=text. couldn't I just insert the text retrieved thru Ajax right into it, considering that I want it be concurrent with the image display? (image is displayed in another div on the left with the id of #pic)

Comment: Yes of course, you'd simply have to save those strings in variables then output them, I'll do an edit to show you how it's done

Comment: In the above code of yours, I see two getHtml's; apparently, one as variable, the other as a function. Did you intentionally used the same name for both?

Comment: It's just a different approach to function declaration, instead of giving a name to a function, I put the function inside a variable. There is no difference between using `var myfn = function(){};` and `function myfn(){}`.

Comment: Sorry I had made a mistake in the goNext() method, should be working fine now

Comment: The Ajax part still doesn't work. I changed some parts but still unsuccessful. Thanks anyway as the logic of your code looks correct.This is the .js file content: http://codepad.org/qCAV6ZBB Gallery work well but the text div that is to hold ajax output is empty.

Comment: Are you sure the ajax part is correct? I'm a newbie to Ajax and I'm not sure if we should also use ajax functions like `$.ajaxSetup()` or something? or $.post(file,...) is sufficient?

Comment: Yes, the .post() method is correct. You can specify additional parameters howere in your case I believe the only two you need are the "url" string and the "success" callback...

Here's the jQuery Documentation on .post() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/...

If you do not find the error, feel free to send me a chat, I'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: **Finally, this made it work:** `var getHtml = function(filename){
   /*
    $.post('ajax/'+filename, function(data) {                               
       textArray.push(data);//Save data inside the array textArray    
    }); 
 */
  /* Send the data using post */
 var posting = $.post( 'ajax/'+filename);
 /* Put the results in a div */
 posting.done(function( data ) {
 var content = $( data).find( 'body' );
 textArray.push( content );
 });
 }` _Thanks anyway, your comments were a big help to me_ :)